# Specifying a start script - Node

Tags: node.js, express

The Node JS application is working fine using node command. (node app.js) I haven't as yet used the start / test scripts in package.json file (As a bonus: If you define scripts.start in your package.json file, you don't need a Procfile) like:

```
{
  "name": "application-name",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "A Node.js app using Express 3",
  "main": "app",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "3.4.0",
    "ejs": "*"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "node",
    "heroku",
    "express"
  ]
}
```

And I'm not getting any error but a message after issuing the command `npm start`

```
> application-name@0.1.0 start E:\nodeFileUpload
> node app.js
```

And then the application exits while if I issue `node app.js` it works fine.
I’m pretty sure that this is configuration related error but I can’t fathom out why.

Comment: Is this on your server or on something like heroku?

Comment: Its happening on my server, and when I deploy this application to heroku its again not running. Should re-installing the Node application fix this problem?

Comment: You can try. I'm really not sure what's going on here; `npm start` always works fine for me. Is this app `express`-based?